# MySQL Query Multiple ID's

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have built a membership application that allows users to assemble projects whose contents are contained across 2 tables ('projects' and 'notes'). Each member can create, update or delete as many projects as they want.

Good so far...

I'd like the members to be able to share their projects with other members they choose. At this point I have built a function that allows Member A to type in an email address in order to share a project (with say, Member B). If that email exists in the DB it updates a third table 'sharing' with the project owner's ID (Member A), the "shared_with" member's ID (Member B) and the project ID. (Perhaps I have gone bullheaded in the wrong direction?)

The problem: How do I query the DB to show Member B all of their own projects + any projects that have been shared with them? The query below illustrates the direction I've been which has been useless. I am trying to say, "Select all from projects where user_id = (me) AND all corresponding projects where my ID is in the 'sharing' table under the 'shared_with' column. ...Oh yeah, and grab that project_id in order to know which project while you're at it."

My brain is mush. Any direction would be sincerely appreciated.

```
function find_all_projects($id) {
  global $db;

  $sql = "
  SELECT * 
    FROM projects 
    LEFT 
    JOIN sharing 
      on projects.id = sharing.project_id 
   WHERE user_id = '" . db_escape($db, $id) . "' 
      OR sharing.shared_with = '" . db_escape($db, $id) . "' 
   ORDER 
      BY project_name
 ";

  $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  confirm_result_set($result);  
  return $result;  
}
```

Comment: You should look into using parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping and injecting the user data into the queries like that.

Comment: I think that the table must be not sharing only but availability at all. And the relation between the project and any person (both owner and users for which this project was shared) are to be mentioned in it. In such scheme the process of project selection is easy enough. The owner is detected by according column in projects table.

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the non-sql stuff for now and instead focus on the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Current Table Structure

From your question I believe your current table structure to be something like the following:

```
TABLE: user                 TABLE: project                                  TABLE: shared

id | email              | | id | user_id | content                      | | id | user_id | project_id
---+--------------------    ---+---------+------------------------------    ---+---------+------------
1  | james@website.com  | | 1  | 1       | Project for James            | | 9  | 1       | 5
2  | hannah@website.com | | 2  | 1       | Some other project for James | | 10 | 3       | 5
3  | lucy@website.com   | | 3  | 2       | Project for Hannah           | | 11 | 1       | 8
   |                    | | 4  | 2       | A new project for hannah     | | 12 | 2       | 8
   |                    | | 5  | 2       | Hannah's pride and Joy       | |
   |                    | | 6  | 3       | Lucy cracking down           | |
   |                    | | 7  | 3       | Lucy's second project        | |
   |                    | | 8  | 3       | Lucy's public stuff          | |
```

### SQL

Example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6KnEsGUmy5PS42usmzyTEX/0

```
SELECT project.id, project.user_id AS owner_id, shared.user_id AS shared_id, project.content
FROM project
    LEFT JOIN shared
        ON project.id = shared.project_id
            AND project.user_id <> ?
WHERE project.user_id = ?
    OR shared.user_id = ?;
```

**N.B.**

The key difference between this SQL statement and the one in your question is

```
AND project.user_id <> ?
```

Without that condition in the `ON` clause you will get duplicate records for every shared project for that user. I.e. if the user has shared the project with 20 users then there will be 20 duplicates.

This is expected behaviour as explained here: [PHP while statement echoes duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64516874/php-while-statement-echoes-duplicates/64517463#64517463)

### PHP

```
$sql   = "
    SELECT project.id, project.user_id AS owner_id, shared.user_id AS shared_id, project.content
    FROM project
        LEFT JOIN shared
            ON project.id = shared.project_id
                AND project.user_id <> ?
    WHERE project.user_id = ?
        OR shared.user_id = ?
";
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("iii", $user_id, $user_id, $user_id);
$query->execute();
```

## Alternate Table Structure

I suggest updating your table structure so that you have three tables (effectively: `users`, `projects`, and `project_users`). The `project_user` table then acts as a conduit between the two entities (`users` and `projects`). In this case storing the relationship between the two (i.e. owner vs shared with).

```
TABLE: user                 TABLE: project                                  TABLE: project_user

id | email              | | id | content                      | | id | user_id | project_id | role
---+--------------------    ---+------------------------------    ---+---------+------------+-----
1  | james@website.com  | | 1  | Project for James            | | 1  | 1       | 1          | 1
2  | hannah@website.com | | 2  | Some other project for James | | 2  | 1       | 2          | 1
3  | lucy@website.com   | | 3  | Project for Hannah           | | 3  | 2       | 3          | 1
   |                    | | 4  | A new project for hannah     | | 4  | 2       | 4          | 1
   |                    | | 5  | Hannah's pride and Joy       | | 5  | 2       | 5          | 1
   |                    | | 6  | Lucy cracking down           | | 6  | 3       | 6          | 1
   |                    | | 7  | Lucy's second project        | | 7  | 3       | 7          | 1
   |                    | | 8  | Lucy's public stuff          | | 8  | 3       | 8          | 1
   |                    | |    |                              | | 9  | 1       | 5          | 2
   |                    | |    |                              | | 10 | 3       | 5          | 2
   |                    | |    |                              | | 11 | 1       | 8          | 2
   |                    | |    |                              | | 12 | 2       | 8          | 2
```

### SQL

Example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/imQZ6cvEEff4VgRQ4v22Qo/0

```
SELECT project.id, project_user.user_id, project_user.role, project.content
FROM project
    JOIN project_user
        ON project_user.project_id = project.id
WHERE project_user.user_id = ?;
```

### PHP

```
$sql   = "
    SELECT project.id, project_user.user_id, project_user.role, project.content
    FROM project
        JOIN project_user
            ON project_user.project_id = project.id
    WHERE project_user.user_id = ?
";
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("i", $user_id);
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another relationship between members and projects with a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `project_members` (
  `project_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `member_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `is_owner` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`, `member_id`));
```

This table allows you to have many members linked to many projects.
The column `is_owner` is a boolean to easily see if the member is the owner or if the project has been shared to him.
Also it would be good to add foreign keys to `project_id` and `member_id`.

Comment: I started down a similar path but ran into spiraling complications with multiple users sharing multiple projects with multiple users.

Comment: @LyleCrumbstorm using a join table like this tends to uncomplicate things; what _spiralling complications_ did you run in to?

Comment: I don't think I fully realized the suggestion first pass. It's the same as yours just without the extended explanation, right?

Comment: @LyleCrumbstorm yes, this is simply implementing the join table as per my answer.

Comment: At the risk of belaboring an already embarrassing question - I've implemented your suggestion successfully (ty!), however, when displaying a user their project summary it now repeats for every shared iteration. I'd like to show the user their project + a list of anyone they are sharing it with. Current table -- 

id | owner_id | shared_with | project_id | role -- 

Additional direction would be so very, very appreciated.

Comment: @LyleCrumbstorm you have to do 2 queries. One to get all owner's projects and another one to get all users related to these projects : `SELECT pm.project_id, member.* FROM member m JOIN project_members pm ON pm.member_id = m.id WHERE pm.project_id IN (list_of_owner_project_ids) AND is_owner = 0` (replace list_of_owner_project_ids with a prepared statement). Also if you use PDO instead of mysqli you could have a really nice array : https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP , Each key of the array could hold the project's id and each value will be all users related to the project